# Gradle Hello World Error

Tags: gradle

I tried my first program in Gradle but I got an error. I wrote a hello world script but I am unable to run it.

My gradle details are:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-07-01 07:45:34 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b6ead6fa452dfdadec484059191eb641d817226c

Groovy:       2.3.3
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_11 (Oracle Corporation 25.11-b03)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 x86
```

My build.gradle is:

```
task hello << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}
```

When I run `gradle -q --info hello`, I get the following error:

```
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'D:\Gradle\build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'Gradle']
Evaluating root project 'Gradle' using build file 'D:\Gradle\build.gradle'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Gradle\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Gradle'.
> Could not find property 'hello' on root project 'Gradle'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to
get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.048 secs
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project
 'Gradle'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.
apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.eva
luate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:470)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProj
ect.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:31)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:128)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradle
Launcher.java:105)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLaun
cher.java:85)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildCon
troller.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.jav
a:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.jav
a:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.
execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRunti
meValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(
CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionRep
ortingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBoots
trap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.j
ava:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'hello'
 on root project 'Gradle'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingExceptio
n(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDyn
amicObject.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeD
ynamicObject.java:94)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.propertyMissing(BasicScript.jav
a:66)
        at build_4hki6gadurnm5c9ejslud0e844.run(D:\Gradle\build.gradle:1)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
        ... 31 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 26.219 secs
amicObject.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeD
ynamicObject.java:94)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.propertyMissing(BasicScript.jav
a:66)
        at build_4hki6gadurnm5c9ejslud0e844.run(D:\Gradle\build.gradle:1)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
        ... 31 more
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine with gradle 2.0. Have You solved it?

Comment: @Opal No I'm still getting the same error. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Run it with `-s`. Maybe it will help You somehow.

Comment: I'm getting a stacktrace. I will the edit the question to include it.

Comment: The build script is fine. Perhaps your actual build script is different, or the script contains some non-printable characters, or your Gradle installation is corrupted. I have a feeling it's the former, as the error output and stack trace shown are not consistent, (One says `Could not find property 'hello'`, the other `Could not find property 'helloWorld'`, so they are definitely not from the same run.)

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Sorry, the stacktrace was for a different file that I was also trying. I have uploaded the correct stacktrace.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from a distance what's going on here. Perhaps your actual build script is different, or the script contains some non-printable characters, or your Gradle installation is corrupted. More concretely, perhaps your build script contains `hello << ...` instead of `task hello << ...`. I recommend to download the gradle-all distribution (if you haven't already) and try to run some builds from the distribution's samples directory.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little bit late, but for those who face the same problem (as you and me) i'll post my solution.

The problem is in the build.gradle encoding, i'm running windows (default encoding ansi) and my build.gradle was UTF-8, I've changed the build.gradle encoding to match my OS encoding and everything works fine now.

Comment: This has bit me in the @$$ more than a few times ;)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, try to build your project first by using the command:

```
gradle build
```

Once this is done, run the task inside your gradle file by saying:

```
gradle -q hello
gradle -q --info hello
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I too got this problem when I wrote my first gradle project. It is because of your file encoding. Do not copy the helloword project. Type these words by your self.

task helloword << {
   println 'pringln hello word'
}

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was update kotlin version in gradle, I changed it from "1.2.40" to "1.3.72"

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}
```